# dll that needs other dll and it's called from a third party

Tags: c++, dll, load, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

This is a really tricky question but here we go:

- I've made a dll that is a plugin for a third party app so I cannot modify that app code. Let's call it app.exe
- My dll (my.dll) also depends on other third party dll (other.dll)

How I can force to load it?
I mean if I put other.dll in the same path as app.exe all works fine, but if I put it on the same path as my.dll it doesn't load my.dll because it depends on other.dll but app.exe don't load it since app.exe uses a really strict way to load dlls.

Obviously I tried to call LoadLibrary but as I expected it doesn't work since it fails before trying to load it.

This question has been a headache for me from a long time.

Regards, F.

Comment: `app.dll`, `app.exe`?? Try to be consistent. You should add where to find all of these into your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Sorry fixed, there is no app.dll it was a typo, I was referring to app.exe in all cases

Comment: About the 3rd party dll: you linked against `other.lib`. Is there a statically linked version of that library? So you link your dll against it and no longer need `other.dll`?